# Best way to render icon and text in JList

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlist

I create a JList constructed with my own sublass of AbstractListModel, the models stores instance of Action class and I had getElementAt() defined as

```
public final Object getElementAt(final int index)
        {
            return ((Action) actionList.get(index)).getValue(Action.NAME);
        }
```

my JList displays a list of action names, which is okay.

But these actions also have an icon defined, so if I do

```
 public final Object getElementAt(final int index)
        {
            return ((Action) actionList.get(index)).getValue(Action.SMALL_ICON)
            );
        }
```

it now displays the icon instead.

But I want both so I tried

```
 public final Object getElementAt(final int index)
        {
            return new JButton(
                    (String)((Action) actionList.get(index)).getValue(Action.NAME),
                    (Icon)((Action) actionList.get(index)).getValue(Action.SMALL_ICON)
            );
        }
```

and now it just outputs the properties of the button instead how come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind reading the javadoc helped !

getElementAt() should just be

```
public final Object getElementAt(final int index)
        {
            return actionList.get(index);
        }
```

then I look the render in the javadoc and modified as follows:

```
class MyCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {
         ImageIcon longIcon = new ImageIcon("long.gif");
         ImageIcon shortIcon = new ImageIcon("short.gif");

        // This is the only method defined by ListCellRenderer.
        // We just reconfigure the JLabel each time we're called.

        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                JList list,              // the list
                Object value,            // value to display
                int index,               // cell index
                boolean isSelected,      // is the cell selected
                boolean cellHasFocus)    // does the cell have focus
        {
            Action action = (Action)value;
            setText((String)action.getValue(Action.NAME));
            setIcon((Icon)action.getValue(Action.SMALL_ICON));
            if (isSelected) {
                setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
                setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
            } else {
                setBackground(list.getBackground());
                setForeground(list.getForeground());
            }
            setEnabled(list.isEnabled());
            setFont(list.getFont());
            setOpaque(true);
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Then set as the Jlists renderer

```
availableList.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
```

and it works.

Comment: You could use a `DefaultListCellRenderer` which is based on a `JLabel` which will take care of most of the work for you, you just need to call `setText` and `setIcon` as required